# SELECT DATA from many to many tables without repetead

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

i have this project where i need to show this table on a webpage:

Result Table (one Bill can have one or many PurchaseOrder)

| BILLID | DESCRIPTION | PO | PO_DESCRIPTION | HES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BILLING1 | 1001,1002 | TEST1,TEST2 | ABC,DFG |
| 2 | BILLING2 | 1003 | TEST3 | HIJ |

Which its created based on 4 tables:

BillingTable

| BILLID | DESCRIPTION | CREATEDAT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BILLING1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2 | BILLING2 | 2022-01-14 |

BillingPos Table (it had a relationship with BillingTable (many-to-one) and with HesTable (one to many)

| ID | FK_BILLID | FK_HES_ID | CREATEDAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2022-01-03 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 2022-01-14 |

Hes Table: it have a relationship with PurchaseOrder Table

| ID | HES_ID | FK_PO_ID | CREATEDAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | DFG | 2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 3 | HIJ | 3 | 2022-01-01 |

PurchaseOrder Table

| ID | PURCHASEORDER | DESCRIPTION | CREATEDAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | TEST1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 1002 | TEST2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 3 | 1003 | TEST3 | 2022-01-01 |

I Know i have to use GROUP_CONCAT to concatenate the POs, Description and HES in one row for the billing id but i can´t figure it out

Comment: I don't know about "GROUP_CONCAT" ... but you *DO* need multiple "joins", and you *DO* need to make sure each table you're joining has the appropriate foreign key(s).  Here are some examples: https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-join-multiple-tables/ or here: https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-join-3-tables-or-more-in-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT Billing.BillID, Billing.Description, Group_Concat(PurchaseOrder) AS PO,
Group_Concat(PurchaseOrder.Description) AS PO_Description, Group_Concat(HES_ID) AS HES
FROM Billing INNER JOIN (PurchaseOrder 
INNER JOIN (HES INNER JOIN BillingPos 
ON HES.ID = BillingPos.FK_HES_ID) 
ON PurchaseOrder.ID = HES.FK_PO_ID) 
ON Billing.BillID = BillingPos.FK_BilledID
GROUP BY BillID, Billing.Description;
```

Comment: Two semi-colons in 1 statement?    (I was only looking at the weird (in my opinion) JOIN syntax used here, which took way too much time to notice the wrong semi-colon... )

Comment: Sorry, I added the ORDER BY afterwards. Typing error. Edited answer. I used Access query builder to construct the joins.

Comment: Final Query:

`SELECT Billing.BillID, Billing.Description, Group_Concat(PurchaseOrder.PURCHARSEORDER) AS PO,
Group_Concat(PurchaseOrder.Description) AS PO_Description, Group_Concat(HES.HES_ID) AS HES
FROM Billing INNER JOIN (PurchaseOrder 
INNER JOIN (HES INNER JOIN BillingPos 
ON HES.ID = BillingPos.FK_HES_ID) 
ON PurchaseOrder.ID = HES.FK_PO_ID) 
ON Billing.BillID = BillingPos.FK_BilledID
GROUP BY BillID, Billing.Description;`